# Specifying sorting order for MappedColumnType based column in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have custom MappedColumnType for Java8 LocalDateTime, defined like this:

```
implicit val localDTtoDate = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp] (
    l => Timestamp.valueOf(l),
    d => d.toLocalDateTime
)
```

Columns of that type are used in table mappings in that way:

```
def timestamp = column[LocalDateTime]("ts")
```

Everything looks good, but i'm not able to sort on that column with different directions, cause it lacks .asc and .desc (and, actually, is not a ColumnOrdered type). How can i add sorting functionality for that type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort and do `.desc` and `.asc`. But, ensure the mapping implicit val is in scope of the query where you are using `.desc` and `.asc`, if not you will get compilation error.